# How can i get the Direction where my Object is moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have started to make Pacman and would like to know how can i write in my code the direction where the Ghost is going ? So if the transform.position.y is growing, its obvious Up Direction and so on....
This is for the Direction Change if they're hit the Wall.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please mark my answer as a solution if it responds your question.

Comment: Not always the direction of movement, but if you need to know the direction of object orientation, there is transform.forward property.

Comment: okay i got the soloutions. I simply had a bool in the Move Function for the directions set up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you've got your game set-up. One manual way you could go about it is by saving the position in a frame, and in the next frame you calculate the difference between the two positions (the previous frame and the actual frame), and divide that by the time that has passed (`Time.deltaTime`).

Another way you could go about it (and I would recommend if possible) is simply getting the Rigidbody component and checking the velocity attribute: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

Keep in mind, since this is a beginner's question, that the fact that an object is moving in a certain direction *may not* come from a ribidbody. As I said, this depends on your exact set-up.